# In the website design using struts2, when a user login, how to keep user information between different website?

Tags: jsp

Recently, I am learning struts 2 and hibernate to build a small web application. I designed a login and register page. After the user registered, he can log in. After the user login, it is a welcome page and then the user can browse other pages. But how to keep the user information among all these pages(Like showing the username above those pages all the time until he logs out)?

I learned the redirect and dispatcher method in struts 2."dispatcher" just lead to a JSP page(I need jump from one action to another action), but it will keep the before actions information in the stack. "redirect" can lead to JSP or another action, but the object information in before action is lost.

So in this situation, like I said, what should I use to keep a user information showing above all the pages?

Comment: Just forgive the poor Engrish (and code ;) http://andrealigios.blogspot.it/2012/08/struts2-write-your-own-interceptor-for.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store it in session, and then on every page retrieve it from session.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is session the old method of JSP and servlet? I want to try using the method in struts 2.

Comment: @Doris not sure what u mean by old method. Store user info in session in the login action class u have, and then in the jsp page, u can retrieve it with struts2 property tag like <s:property value="#session.userInfo" />.

Comment: I got it! Thank you! At first, I still confused about which interface should I implement. But then I see [link] (http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/struts/working-with-httpsession-in-struts2-a-login-example) . Then I know it.